# Selecting values from pandas dataframe based off of columns with min/max values in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with different quarters of the year as columns and particular locations as rows:

Temperature:

|  | q_1 | q_2 | q_3 | q_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 50 | 0 | 5 |
| B | 6 | 0 | 30 | 1 |
| C | 60 | 2 | 9 | 16 |

Precipitation

|  | q_1 | q_2 | q_3 | q_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 18 | 1 | 0 | 7 |
| B | 6 | 13 | 12 | 3 |
| C | 3 | 20 | 4 | 0 |

I am trying to create another dataframe whose columns are populated by the temperatures for the wettest/driest quarter and the precipitation of the warmest/coolest quarters for each location:

DF_new:

|  | temp_wettest | temp_driest | precip_warmest | precip_coolest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 1 | 12 | 13 |
| C | 2 | 16 | 3 | 20 |

I have been trying to use idxmax:

```
temp = pd.DataFrame({'q_1' : [10,6,60],
                     'q_2' : [50,0,2],
                     'q_3' : [0,30,9],
                     'q_4' : [5,1,16]},index=['A','B','C'])
prec = pd.DataFrame({'q_1' : [18,6,3],
                     'q_2' : [1,13,20],
                     'q_3' : [0,12,4],
                     'q_4' : [7,3,0]},index=['A','B','C'])

DF_new = pd.DataFrame({'temp_wettest': temp[prec.idxmax(axis=1)],
                       'temp_driest' : temp[prec.idxmin(axis=1)],
                       'precip_warmest': prec[temp.idxmax(axis=1)],
                       'precip_coolest': prec[temp.idxmin(axis=1)]},index=['A','B','C'])

<OUT>
    temp_wettest    temp_driest precip_warmest  precip_coolest
A      (q, _, 1)      (q, _, 3)      (q, _, 2)       (q, _, 3)
B      (q, _, 2)      (q, _, 4)      (q, _, 3)       (q, _, 2)
C      (q, _, 2)      (q, _, 4)      (q, _, 1)       (q, _, 2)
```

I get why idxmax isn't working (it's just passing in a list of column names), but I'm not sure how to get the actual values into the new dataframe. I've also tried using pd.apply(), but I'm unsure of what function to use.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know the best alternative for `lookup`, but this might work.

```
DF_new = pd.DataFrame({'temp_wettest': temp.stack().loc[list(map(tuple,prec.idxmax(axis=1).reset_index().to_numpy()))].tolist(),
                       'temp_driest' : temp.stack().loc[list(map(tuple,prec.idxmin(axis=1).reset_index().to_numpy()))].tolist(),
                       'precip_warmest': prec.stack().loc[list(map(tuple,temp.idxmax(axis=1).reset_index().to_numpy()))].tolist(),
                       'precip_coolest': prec.stack().loc[list(map(tuple,temp.idxmin(axis=1).reset_index().to_numpy()))].tolist()})
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using your idea, but used the multiIndex method: 
 `'temp_wettest':temp.stack().loc[pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(prec.idxmax(axis=1).reset_index())].values`

Answer (score 1):

If you have Pandas version < 1.2.0, try `lookup`:

```
DF_new = pd.DataFrame({'temp_wettest': temp.lookup(prec.index, prec.idxmax(axis=1)),
                       'temp_driest' : temp.lookup(prec.index, prec.idxmin(axis=1)),
                       'precip_warmest': prec.lookup(temp.index, temp.idxmax(1)),
                       'precip_coolest': prec.lookup(temp.index, temp.idxmin(1))
                      })
```

Output:

```
   temp_wettest  temp_driest  precip_warmest  precip_coolest
0            10            0               1               0
1             0            1              12              13
2             2           16               3              20
```

Comment: It throws a depreciation warning, but works. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason that lookup is being depreciated? It seems like a useful function, and there doesn’t appear to be a great replacement for it.

Comment: @rhug123 I don't know. The devs seem to think that nobody is using `lookup`. There was an attempt to un-deprecate it [on github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/39171) but it was closed.

Comment: That’s interesting. The alternative that is listed to use melt and loc doesn’t seem nearly as good.